# {spring:mvcUrl('xxx#search').build()} causes syntax error in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, spring, jsp

I'm using STS 3.7.1(Eclipse) and I realized that every time I write the code below in JSP file, STS notice me syntax error.

```
{spring:mvcUrl('xxx#search').build()}
```

Here is my screen shot.
[image]

Does anyone know how to supress this syntax error?